Gitlab ci pipeline: logic if + changes
Please help me.
sonarqube-check:  
  image: 
  script: 
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' 
      changes:
      - Implementation/*

Create MR develop with file change -> main: Pipeline not run
If I comment changes -> pipeline run ok

I think you need to rework the question as its really difficult to understand what your asking.
